# What is the Fill option for in the Line tool in Photoshop 2021

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The Line tool has been changed in Ps 2021 and it no longer draws a rectangle but a path-like formula with no dimensions and it only becomes visible after setting the Stroke. It's reflected in the fact that the Line cannot be used in Pixels mode (which is greyed out), and it is logical as it has no dimensions. But the Fill option in the Shape mode is still available, and I can't think of any scenario in which it might be used as it appears the Stroke is the only way to control the color and thickness of the Line. So my question is why the Fill option hasn't been greyed out? It seems redundant to me.

Comment: I think you should post this in the Photoshop feedback forums. The changes to the line tool seem a little unpolished... Which has been pretty common occurrence since CC launched. I would guess the fill color can be set because you can add new anchor points with for example the pen tool and then drag the point(s) to turn the line into a shape with fill. Why that would be needed is beyond me.

Comment: But there are several weird things about that. When you do that, the starting anchor point looks kinda broken. The end anchor point looks ok though. Changing it to rounded corners makes the starting anchor point look normal. Also both starting point and the end point can only be deleted, so you can't like continue the line. So basically it seems they made it work similar to how pen tool works... but some restrictions oddities.